# This variable is an array. Why is it returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, return, return-value

This is a partial attempt at solving the [Eloquent Javascript challenge in Chapter 4](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html), A List. theArray returns undefined, but if I just print its value it is what I would expect (An array of values). Why does it return undefined?

```
var obj = {"value":"C","rest":{"value":"B","rest":{"value":"A"}}};

var theArray =[];

var listToArray = function(list) {
  theArray.push(list.value);
    if(list.rest !== undefined) {
      listToArray(list.rest);
    } else return theArray; //console.log(theArray); returns the expected value
}

console.log(listToArray(obj));
```

Comment: You are only returning from the `else` branch, but not from the `if`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return the recursive call,

```
 if(list.rest !== undefined) {
      return listToArray(list.rest);
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mh8jgwdo/)

If you do not return the recursive call, then the `array` which is from the final function stack will not be returned instead `undefined` will be returned.

Comment: That definitely solved the problem, but I don't understand why. What's the difference between returning the function call and simply making the function call? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Landfizzle This is somewhat difficult to understand. So I am giving you a practical example. Consider the function calls as persons standing in a straight line, say 5 persons. Each person having 2 bucks(values for array) in their hand, our aim is to collect all the bucks from those 5 people. So we will ask the first to send his money to the second one and the second one add his money with that and pass it to the next and so on until the 5 th person. Now the 5th person will return the overall collected money to 4, 4 will return to 3 and so on.

Comment: @Landfizzle what will happen if 3 drops the money. Can we get all the money from the 1st one? No, because 3rd one dropped it. So in order to receive money properly, every one has to return the money properly. "If a function doesn't returns anything then from there undefined will start to return until the beginning."

Comment: So that metaphor describes the program written with the return statement, correct? What would the metaphor look like with just a simple function call?